# Add new fields in "Files/Links Upload" tt_content

Tags: typo3-9.x

I use `File Links [uploads]` Content Element to show list of files, and I need to add a field on this CE to show description.

I found this on the documentation : https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/8.7/en-us/ExtensionArchitecture/ExtendingTca/Examples/#example-2-extending-the-tt-content-table but I couldn't apply it because of a lack of skill with PHP and T3 Customization.

In which file I should add the follwing code :

```
CREATE TABLE tt_content (
    tx_files_description tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL
);
```

How can I customize the follwing code ? :

```
$temporaryColumn = array(
    'tx_files_description' => array (
            'exclude' => 0,
            'label' => 
'LLL:EXT:examples/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tt_content.tx_files_description',
            'config' => array (
                    'type' => 'check',
            )
    )
 );
  \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addTCAcolumns(
    'tt_content',
    $temporaryColumn
  );
 \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addFieldsToPalette(
    'tt_content',
    'visibility',
    'tx_files_description',
    'after:linkToTop'
 );
```

Comment: what does this field do exactly? A description needs most of the time a VARCHAR definition in the .sql but you have it as boolean. It is a litte bit confusing

Comment: It's a simple text field to add/show text before the files links. On BE it will look like that : https://imgur.com/1d8Zh48 and on FE : https://imgur.com/ubbxZue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do it in such a complicated way?

`tt_content`records already has a lot of fields which are not used for rendering the CType `uploads`.

Even the description field is available, so it is no RTE field. (all CEs have this field for information in the backend only)

You only need to use it in the FE-rendering, though you need to modify the fluid template.

---

If you need a RTE field, you should activate the field `bodytext` in the BE form, as it comes with a proper definition and rendering.
You still have to insert the rendered field in the fluid template.

Comment: for “Files/Links Upload” tt_content type you mean this filed can used to add description and render it on FE https://imgur.com/hKU5rjz ?

Comment: this field should be availiable as all fields are available in the FE. just insert `<f:debug title="fields for uploads`>{_all}</f:debug>` into your copy of the fluid template for uploads.

Comment: yes, works good, I found the `rowDescription` field on the data of my tt_content, so I just  rendered it in the template : \Resources\Private\Templates\ContentElements\Uploads.html `<div class="Description">{data.rowDescription -> f:format.html()}</div>` Thanks @Bernd Wilke πφ

Answer (score 1):

Since you created your own content element i can not really know how to position the lement, but what i can do is to help you create it. I just tested on my TYPO3 installtion and it works.

**ext_tables.sql**

```
CREATE TABLE tt_content (
    tx_files_description text,
);
```

**yourExtension/Configuration/TCA/Overrides/tt_content.php**

```
$temporaryColumn = [
'tx_files_description' => [
    'exclude' => true,
    'label' => 'LLL:EXT:your_extension_key/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf:tt_content.tx_files_description',
    'config' => [
        'type' => 'text',
        'enableRichtext' => false,
    ],
 ],
];

\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addTCAcolumns(
   'tt_content',
   $temporaryColumn
 );

\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addToAllTCAtypes(
   'tt_content',
   'tx_files_description',
   'general',
   'before:media'

 );
```

Assuming that you re using TYPO3 v9 go to the module Maintenance and press **Analyze Database**, then clear all cache.

If you are on TYPO3 v7-v8 then go to the install module and **Run compare database** (something like that). Clear the cache.

**Then on your extended tab:**

[image]

Best regards

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have 2 question please : 1. will I have to create my own extension? 2.which ext_tables.sql files should I edit (there are serval ext_tables.sql files on my instalation) ?

Comment: do you have a sitepackage?

Comment: no, I'm using v9 and I don't have sitepackage installed (I'm in the learning stage on T3)

Comment: in order to get an ext_tables.sql and the tt_content.php, you need to create your own extension. Bernd Wilke πφ is right though. You could just use the bodytext in your content element. I just gave you a way to do it yourself

Comment: yes, Bernd Wilke πφ is right though, works good for me, thanks @Aristeidis Karavas